# Case assignment to Agents: Constraints are time to complete each case and agents available time

Tags: r, loops

I have to assign each case to agents. Where a case can be executed by only one agent and multiple cases can be assigned to a single agent based on the following constraints:

1. Each case has a specific time to complete and (No limit of time)
2. Each agent has some available time (Agent available time cannot be more than 240 mins)

Sometimes the number of cases can be greater than the number of available agents and the number of agents can be greater than the number of cases

Two available datasets are:

case_data:

```
CASE_ID CASE_COM_TIME
1   54
2   56
3   56
4   504
5   505
6   330
7   67
8   120
9   130
10  54
```

agent_data:

```
AGENT   AGENT_TIME
A   78
B   180
C   240
D   120
E   240
F   46
```

How to resolve this problem using R programming?

Expected output: Just to show an example of what I require. Not the optimal one

```
CASE_ID CASE_COM_TIME   AGENT
1   54  B
2   56  B
3   56  B
4   504 C
5   505 G
6   330 E
7   67  A
8   120 D
9   130 A
10  54  F
```

Comment: Do you have a particular algorithm in mind? What are the constraints? What makes a solution optimal?

Comment: Hi Rohit, The constraints are within the agents available time and the case completion time, the case can be assigned to agents. if you look at the example data you may get some idea. Like if a case takes 500 mins then it can be assigned to agents with 240 mins only. And another scenario can be if some cases take  52,54,56 mins respectively and an agent has 130 mins available time then also we can assign it to that agents, considering we don't have any other suitable options. I don't have any solution in my mind. I just wanted to allocate the case to agents considering those criteria